# Get time of last update on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to get the time of the last update from Elastic Beanstalk? I'm working on a project that pushes code frequently, it would be helpful for our debugging to be able to output the time of the last update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the command line interface you can use the describe-appliaction-versions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/CLIReference-cmd-DescribeApplicationVersions.html

You can also get it from the application itself using the various [SDKs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.UsingAEB.html).

See for example for PHP here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.ElasticBeanstalk.ElasticBeanstalkClient.html#_describeApplicationVersions

You just need to make sure that your application has the permission to call the API. The best way to do it is using Role: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.aeb.html

Comment: Is it possible to have it automatically increment? We could manually update the code anyway; I'm looking for a way that doesn't add a step to our deploy process

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want to get.
The call above will give you the list of versions, and the last version will be the one that you want. The information on this version will have the time of the last update.

Comment: Ah, my bad; I didn't quite understand what you meant. That looks promising…does the version get incremented on every update? Is there a way to access that information on the site itself, rather than through the CLI?

Comment: Yes, it is tracking the updates to the application. You can access this API through most of the SDks (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.UsingAEB.html), depends on your programming language (PHP as well-http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/). Updated the answer above with details.